# Can this site be just as useful as being tutored?

Tags: discussion

I'm in my second year of high school and I chose to follow math studies and based on our first lesson "Logic" I'm starting to question my abilities in doing Maths. I never got any help from any tutor and I'm still keeping my vow to try and do Maths on my own. But this time I'm really stuck in this lesson I don't know what to do ! I want to continue no matter what and I don't want to feel that I'm useless but I'm afraid if my volition isn't enough too.

That's why I thought that maybe this site could be more helpful if I use it just like a tutor in Maths ?

Comment: It is not very clear to me what specifically you want to ask, but at a glance it seems your questions are fairly well received, so your usage seems fine.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, all what I'm asking is can I for example ask for help in a lesson if I find it hard to learn by myself

Comment: It is not clear what specifically you mean with "ask for help in a lesson." You should be careful to try to ask a specific question. Linking to a document of several pages length and asking "please explain" will not work. But as long as you manage to ask a *self-contained* question about the content here it should be fine.

Comment: Anyway, give it a try, one question at a time and watch the feedback you receive and try to react on it. Generally the site is not shy to push back on content that is not acceptable. To decide in abstract can be hard though.

Comment: If you're looking for something like a tutor in Maths, why not hire a tutor in Maths?

Comment: On first glance, I misread the title here as "**Can this site be just as useful as being tortured?**"

Comment: You can always self-study and ask some question on this site.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, absolutely not.  As mentioned in other answers, there really is very little interaction between the OP and the answerers.  If you are an OP, you ask a question.  It gets answered by somebody.  You may or may not understand the entire solution provided.  Not only is the answerer not under any obligation to help you further, but (s)he is discouraged from doing so here.

In reality, I have found that there are folks on this site that, for whatever reasons be it too much free time on their hands, overeagerness, desperation for rep score, lack of self-confidence and awareness,..., that are more than happy to provide free tutoring services to those lucky and/or manipulative enough to recognize they are being served by a sucker.  So if you see someone who keeps answering your follow-up questions, no matter how little work you are willing to do on your own, congratulations!

(I am still amazed that some of these free service providers have tried to convince me that this is our duty to tutor random, lazy people on this site endlessly!  Does time not mean anything to these people?  Do they have any dignity?)

So, please, use this site first and see how far you can get on your own.  If you continue to be stuck and need to ask a lot of follow-up questions, then you likely need a tutor.

Comment: I take issue with this entire answer. "In reality, I have found that there are folks on this site that, for whatever reasons be it too much free time on their hands, overeagerness, desperation for rep score, lack of self-confidence and awareness,..., that are more than happy to provide free tutoring services to those lucky and/or manipulative enough to recognize they are being served by a sucker." Yes you missed a reason: wanting to help other people and do good in the world.

Comment: All you've done is degrade these people, who you clearly don't like, by saying that they "have no life", "are impulsive", "selfish", "lack self-confidence" and "don't understand anything that's going on around them", none of which is true. Not only have you missed the main reason that people on this site effectively 'tutor', you've completely misportrayed it in the opposite direction from reality and have done so using loaded language.

Comment: "I am still amazed that some of these free service providers have tried to convince me that this is our duty to tutor random, lazy people on this site endlessly!" - I'm not saying it's obligatory of course, it's just the nice thing to do. And how dare you portray those who have had a sucky experience with math as 'lazy' because they have been demotivated by it. Are you amazed because you're a sociopath? And so what if the person is random? We're all together on this planet.

Comment: "Does time not mean anything to these people?" Actually it does and no one's expecting you to spend all this time on your site but leaving a half-answer just leaves the asker confused and frustrated. "Do they have any dignity?" - oh I see, I get it now, those who truly want to help others have no dignity

Comment: "If you continue to be stuck and need to ask a lot of follow-up questions, then you likely need a tutor." - way to stigmatize it. Great going.

Comment: "Not only is the answerer not under any obligation to help you further, but (s)he is discouraged from doing so here." - you know, in the teaching profession they call this bad teaching. And if you're not here to help and teach others then you're a selfish b*****d who's in it for themselves. Almost none of the questions on this site end up having significant importance to the one who asked the question, so don't give me the "stack exchange's mission is to build a library of knowledge" crap. Such a site would've never become so successful.

Comment: "that are more than happy to provide free tutoring services to those lucky and/or manipulative enough to recognize they are being served by a sucker." - you're not a sucker because you want to help someone.

Comment: "You may or may not understand the entire solution provided." What's considered sufficient explanation to you may not be so to someone else. You can't just sit back with an answer potentially missing details and expect the asker to be satisfied, and definitely not intellectually. Either that or it's no better than telling the asker they're too stupid to understand the subject. And that your word is final, which it most certainly isn't

Comment: And ya know what is most annoying of all? People like you shutting down people who effectively are using the site to tutor. You don't have to do it yourself obviously, but don't shut down the people who do want to do it. You don't have to join us but at least leave us in peace for god's sake. It's none of your business if we want to spend extra time helping other people. And no, it's not for damn rep.

Comment: "there really is very little interaction between the OP and the answerers" every relationship without communication is bound to be a good one

Comment: Ok, so you took an answer I wrote *six years* ago and got so worked up about it that you wrote (and maybe are still writing) a multipart answer expressing your indignance at the opinion that this site is for people who enjoy mathematics?  Well, if that is how you have fun on this site don’t let me, uhhh…., shut you down. The future is yours, feel free to police it as you see fit.

Comment: "If you are an OP, you ask a question." - simpleminded attitude towards imparting knowledge "So if you see someone who keeps answering your follow-up questions, no matter how little work you are willing to do on your own, congratulations!" - once again, some people are bad or demotivated at math of no fault of their own, but here, we can fix that, or at least a bit, a perhaps even heal the trauma some people have experienced with math indirectly.

Comment: This community of great people could be doing so much good. Instead, asking questions on this site has given me more mathematical trauma and angst than school or college ever could. The moderators of this community mostly lack perspective of the vunerable and the site as a whole.

Comment: Although I make a vast generalization here, a basic model of this site could equally be that of secure anserers taking advantage of insecure askers to gain absurd amounts of rep and run the site, reinforcing their views even more like in an echo chamber and alienating those outside (this happens through a variety of methods which I'd care to explain). It's a systemic problem corrupting every part of the site. The word rep is an absolute misnomer, too.

Comment: "Well, if that is how you have fun on this site don’t let me" - I'm not having fun doing this "shut you down" - well, that got completely removed from context (the original context was tutoring, clearly not about what I'm doing atm). "The future is yours, feel free to police it as you see fit." That would be nice, but is not encouraging people to not answer follow up questions also policing? If we can agree to leave eachother's types alone on this site, then there is no problem. But in reality we are policed for simply helping others. I write no more unless you respond.

Comment: "this site is for people who enjoy mathematics" - sorry, I did not realize earlier that this was your motive. It is mine too. But when I see people on this site getting bullied and abandoned, I feel obligated to pick up their slack. I agree this site has both its good sides and its bad sides. I do enjoy many parts of this site, like, a lot.

Comment: actually my original motive on this site was to get questions on college level math answered before I was actually in college, and could find the resources. I guess came for "expert answers to your questions" and the active community that math stack exchange advocates. And they're not wrong that the site really does offer this. Along the way I've also found a lot of questions and answers I simply enjoy. And I've seen a lot of bullying, too.

Comment: (cont.) None of it was my original intent, but nevertheless it exists here. I wouldn't feel so obligated to, essentially, tutor, if I wasn't trying to clean up the emotional problems that others have left, in particular on innocent first time users. The reason I'm writing so much to you, is, because the word "tutoring" reminded me of the one thing this site is missing (neigh, *rejects*) ok, now I'm really done, like I'd said before

Answer (score 2):

"Tutor" implies heavy back-and-forth interaction with a human being — the sort of thing that the stackexchange network *explicitly* discourages on the main sites, is not designed to support, and to some extent is actually designed to prevent. (e.g. that's why comment threads don't look like forum posts)

From the tour,

> Avoid questions that ... are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.

However, the site *does* include chat rooms. I can't say how useful they are or how they compare to dedicated discussion forums.

---

However, if you can distill your problems down to self-contained questions or prompts for exposition within sufficiently narrow constraints (or even questions about how to ask questions!)... well, that's what the site is meant for!

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what you want. If you want 
- someone to introduce you to a topic 
- someone to review a specific topic
- someone to guide your studies
then I think a tutor is what you want. In particular a tutor should be someone who can distill a topic and make sure that you catch certain important high points. Many math books can be used for self-study, but they can contain much more information than you necessarily need/want.

This site can help you answer specific questions about in specific topics. The key is that your questions is well defined and not open ended. There are examples of nice larger context questions such as asking for examples of something or applications of something. You can also ask for references and book recommendations, but these should be as specific as possible.

So, in my opinion, what is most useful is dependent on what you want.